# How can I check if the sum of some brands is smaller than the total of that brand and return those who aren't in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a data like this [image: Table] and I need to sum the Value of the "Brand" rows and check if it is smaller than the "Total" rows Value for each Sub_Category and to return a table with the results and if it's easier only with those who fail the check, something like this [image: table], in R.

So far I've started with this:

result<- with(df, sum(df$`Value`[df$Brand_Type == 'Brand']))

but it only returns the sum for all of them so I've also tried a group_by but I could not get anywhere close to the wanted result so I really need some help here.

EDIT:

Sample of full data, I have over 900 observations in total:

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(Year = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011), Category = c("Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", 
"Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", 
"Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Puma", "Puma", "Puma", "Nike", 
"Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike"), Sub_Category = c("Adidas", 
"Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", 
"Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Puma", "Puma", 
"Puma", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike Air", "Nike Air", "Nike Air"
), Segment = c("Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", 
"Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas Originals", 
"Adidas Originals", "Adidas Originals", "Puma", "Puma", "Puma", 
"Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike Air", "Nike Air", "Nike Air"), 
    Brand_Type = c("Total", "Brand", "Brand", "Manufacturer", 
    "Manufacturer", "Manufacturer", "Total", "Brand", "Brand", 
    "Brand", "Total", "Brand", "Brand", "Total", "Brand", "Brand", 
    "Total", "Brand", "Brand", "Total", "Brand", "Brand"), Value = c(12, 
    3, 4, 12, 1, 2, 8, 5, 3, 1, 6, 2, 3, 19, 12, 11, 25.8, 11, 
    5, 16, 9, 9)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

[image: full]

Comment: Please replicate your dataset on R...

Comment: Can you share the data with `dput()`? Otherwise it's difficult to adjust the code.

Comment: Yes, I've edited in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Sub_Category, Brand_Type) %>% 
  mutate(Sum = sum(Value)) %>% 
  group_by(Sub_Category) %>% 
  mutate(Total = Value[Brand_Type == "Total"], Change = Total - Sum, Value = NULL) %>% 
  filter(Sum > lag(Sum)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  Category Sub_Category Brand_Type   Sum Total Change
  <chr>    <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Puma     Puma         Brand         23    19     -4
2 Nike     Nike Air     Brand         18    16     -2
```

With **base R**

```
df_sum <- aggregate(Value ~ ., df, sum)

df_t <- cbind(df_sum, Total = df_sum$Value[df_sum$Brand_Type == "Total"])

cbind(df_t[df_t$Value > df_t$Total,], 
  Change = df_t[df_t$Value > df_t$Total,"Total"] - 
             df_t[df_t $Value > df_t$Total,"Value"])
  Category Sub_Category Brand_Type Value Total Change
3     Nike     Nike Air      Brand    18    16     -2
4     Puma         Puma      Brand    23    19     -4
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Puma", 
"Puma", "Puma", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike"
), Sub_Category = c("Adidas", "Adidas", "Adidas", "Puma", "Puma", 
"Puma", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike", "Nike Air", "Nike Air", "Nike Air"
), Brand_Type = c("Total", "Brand", "Brand", "Total", "Brand", 
"Brand", "Total", "Brand", "Brand", "Total", "Brand", "Brand"
), Value = c(12, 3, 4, 19, 12, 11, 25.8, 11, 5, 16, 9, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

#### Edit 2

##### mod Data

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Year, Segment, bt = Brand_Type != "Total") %>% 
  mutate(Sum = sum(Value)) %>% group_by(Year, Segment) %>% 
  mutate(Total = Value[Brand_Type == "Total"], 
    Change = Total - Sum, Value = NULL, bt = NULL) %>% 
  filter(Sum > lag(Sum)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 × 8
   Year Category Sub_Category Segment  Brand_Type   Sum Total Change
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>        <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2011 Adidas   Adidas       Adidas   Brand         22    12    -10
2  2012 Adidas   Adidas       Adidas   Brand          9     8     -1
3  2011 Puma     Puma         Puma     Brand         23    19     -4
4  2011 Nike     Nike Air     Nike Air Brand         18    16     -2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer it definitely works but I have one more question, what if in the Brand_Type I would have a third value, Manufacturer for example, what should I change to your code?

Comment: @nbuser Depends what behavior is desired. Treat like Brand, ignore or something entirely different?

Comment: Treat exactly the same, let's say Puma was labelled as a Manufacturer in the Brand_Type.

Comment: @nbuser That works without change. Only requirement is keeping "Total" and all Brands need to have the same Type within their group. I'll post an example below the original answer.

Comment: Wildberd Thanks for your help, I assumed that it needs a change because as soon as I tried to use it I got this Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Total`.
i `Total = Value[Brand_Type == "Total"]`.
i `Total` must be size 7 or 1, not 2.
i The error occurred in group 1: Sub_Category = "Adidas".                                                    I figured it out now that the problem is that I have values that repeat in the Sub_Category, for example Adidas, once as a Manufacturer, once as a Brand and only one Total, I'll edit my questions with the exact example.

Comment: @nbuser The size of the vector Total is always the number of rows. 12 in case of the example data. I can't tell why its 2 in your case. You're sure you using it on the right data? Were you able to run the example with the data provided?

Comment: I took a closer look to see what do you mean and I see it now, your code worked just fine with the data provided but what I forgot to mention in the example is that I have a joined data with multiple years so it definitely finds more Totals than just one per Sub_Category and also I have to include a Segment column too so it adds a Total for that one too. I attached a more accurate example from my full data in the question as an EDIT, in the sample I originally posted was just my simple way of putting it out and not thinking that all other columns may affect the code.

Comment: @nbuser I added a `dplyr` solution for the new data.

Comment: Wilberg, thank you for the help, is there any easy way to separate them? the manufacturers and brands, let's say I would like to check only if the Manufacturer < Total and leave Brand out or the other way, Brand < Total and leave the Manufacturer out?

Comment: @nbuser Simply add `df %>% filter(Brand_Type == "Manufacturer" | Brand_Type == "Total") %>% ...` at the beginning.